# Getting a specific column to add their values using loop with mysql returns NaN

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the code below with a sql query. I'm trying to add the values of  Totalcost column in the query using for loop. And what I get is NaN when I try to run the program and it prints 6 times when it should only print once

I've used rows[0].Totalcost to get the column i wanted and it prints only the first row of the result. Then I've used loop to add it in the totalcost variable. When I console log it returns NaN

````
router.get("/requestvoucher/:rvnumber/:status/:to", isLoggedIn,  function(req, res){
    var reqvoucher = req.params.rvnumber;
    var status = req.params.status;
    var to = req.params.to;
    var totalcost;
    var sql = `SELECT Itemname, Itemcode, Quantity, Totalcost, Description, Brand, Category, RVnumber, Requestto,Requeststatus FROM billingdata.rvrequest WHERE rvnumber=?`;
    query = db.query(sql,[reqvoucher], function(err, rows){
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }else{
            //console.log(rows[0].Totalcost);
//My Console.logs prints 6 times i have no idea why
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var totalcost =+ rows[0].Totalcost[i]; 
                }
                console.log(totalcost);
            res.render('updaterequest', {dataUpdate: rows, rvNumber: reqvoucher, reqStats: status, reqto: to});
        }
    });
});```

I'm expecting the sum of the Totalcost column using for loop and printed it once.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace
`var totalcost =+ rows[0].Totalcost[i];` with `var totalcost += rows[0].Totalcost[i];`

And another one. Looks like your rows[0].Totalcost[i] sometimes is not a number. Thus your sum can be `NaN`. To prevent this you can use something like
`totalcost+=isNaN(rows[0].Totalcost[i])?0:rows[0].Totalcost[i]`

Comment: Totalcost column is a double